# Finding rows where one field is equal and another differs

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 14.

I have two tables with sites, timestamps and some other information. I want to get all rows in table B having a site in table A but another timestamp. All rows in table A are also in table B and there are no duplicate with same site and date, so the situation is like this:

Table A

```
site | date
------------------
A    | 2022-01-01
A    | 2022-02-01
B    | 2022-01-01
B    | 2022-02-02
C    | 2022-01-03
C    | 2022-02-01
```

Table B

```
site | date
------------------
A    | 2022-01-01
A    | 2022-02-01
A    | 2022-02-02
B    | 2022-01-01
B    | 2022-02-02
C    | 2022-01-03
C    | 2022-02-01
C    | 2022-03-01
```

I want to run a query that gives

```
site | date
------------------
A    | 2022-02-02
C    | 2022-03-01
```

I tried to run

```
select B.site,B.date from B left join A on A.site = B.site where A.date != B.date;
```

But of cource gave me all A and C rows.

How do I say in SQL: Give me rows with dates that does not exist for a given station in the other table?

Both tables are around 1000 rows, so a slow query (within reasonable limits) is no disaster.